# variable within a object not updating in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object which is initialized like

```
  var x = function(){
       var result = 5,
       clear = function(){
          result = 0;
        };
      return {
        result: result,
        clear: clear      
     }           
  }
```

I am later creating a new instance of `x` using `var y = new x();`

but when i try setting the `value` `y.result = 5;` and want to clear the `result` value to `0` I call `y.clear();`

However it is not resetting the `y.result` to `0`... Not sure why?

Anything that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Numbers are immutable, the `result` on top is not the same as `result` in the object you're returning. Make a getter function.

Comment: You should be using `var y = x();`, not `var y = new x();`.  `x` is not a constructor function.  (It does not write to `this`.)

Comment: how would that look like?

Comment: `clear` is a setter because it sets the `result` variable. A getter would return the `result` variable.

Comment: You already have a function `clear`. Just make a `getResult` function in the same way.

Comment: And ladies and gentlemen, this is why Douglas Crockford doesn't like new.

Comment: @Siddharth ehh not really. Firslty the lowercase `x` is violating the convention he stresses, and secondly this is just not knowing what you are doing, which nobody approves of. If you use a keyword you should maybe google how to use it (hence my downvote).

Comment: Actually, you're right. I just wanted to point out the general confusion with regards to the new keyword and his dislike of it hence. (He mentions that using new on a function and not a constructor and the reverse case are very common errors. This is an example of such an error.)

Comment: About constructor functions and prototype: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+prototype&tab=newest

Comment: As I have said so often: Assigning a value to a property or variable **never** changes the value of another variable or property (exceptions: global scope and `with` statement). JavaScript is pass/call/assign by value: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value

Comment: @Siddharth: FWIW, it doesn't matter in this case whether `new` is used or not. The result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that numbers are referenced by value. Assigning value to `result` variable from `clear` function won't change value of `result` on new `x` instance.

There are several ways to go about this:

1. Store data on `this`, then modify it there inside constructor and method, I find it easier to understand and more readable. This is probably what you wanted to begin with:

   ```
   function x () {
       this.result = 5;
   }

   x.prototype.clear = function () {
       this.result = 0;
   }

   var z = new x();
   // z.result === 5
   z.clear()
   // z.result === 0;
   ```
2. Define getter and setter on returned object, so instance `result` would return\set closured variable:

   ```
   function x () {
       var result = 5;

       function clear () {
           result = 0;
       }

       var out = {
           clear: clear
       };

       Object.defineProperty(out, "result", {
           get: function () {
               return result;
           },
           set: function (value) {
               result = value;
           }
       });

       return out;
   }

   var z = new x();
   // z.result === 5
   z.clear()
   // z.result === 0;
   z.result = 10
   // z.result === 10;
   z.clear()
   // z.result === 0;
   ```

Comment: Not, IE7/8 do not support defineProperty on objects. The first solution should work there just fine, though. If you really want to go with closured var approach, then all external access to result should be done using function(s).

Answer (score 3):

Within your function:

```
var x = function(){
       var result = 5,
       clear = function(){
          result = 0;
```

The identifier *result* in this function has a closure to the variable *result* in the outer function (i.e. outer execution context).

```
        };
      return {
        result: result,
```

That assigns the value of the **variable** named result to the **object property** named result.

```
        clear: clear      
     }           
  }
```

So later when you call `y.clear()` you are setting the value of the variable held in the closure, which does not update the object property named result.

If you want *x* to be a constructor, then:

```
function X() {
  this.result = 5;
  this.clear = function() {
    this.result = 0;
  }
}
```

So now:

```
var y = new X();
y.clear();
console.log(y.result); // 0
```

Note that it is convention for constructors to have a name starting with a capital letter. You can learn more about how to use the *new* operator on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

To leverage ECMAScript inheritance, put the *clear* function on the constructor's prototype so that all instances inherit the one method, rather than each having its own:

```
function X() {
  this.result = 5;
}

X.prototype.clear = function() {
  this.result = 0;
}
```